# /favicon.ico after login in Node JS

Tags: html, node.js, express, redirect, favicon

I have created a `login/register` system using express (passport) on my website and I am saving the originalUrl before the user was redirected to the login page but every time after the login, the user is redirected to `/favicon.ico`  instead of the saved Url. Could someone tell me what is the cause of the issue?

My app.use():

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!['/login'].includes(req.originalUrl)) {
        req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
    }
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
})
```

My /login get and post request:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
})

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res) => {
    const redirectUrl = req.session.returnTo || '/';
    console.log(redirectUrl);
    delete req.session.returnTo;
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
})
```

Comment: A user should never be redirected to `/favico.ico`.  If that's really happening, then it's a serious error in your server code and you will have to show us your server code for us to recommend what to fix.  More likely, you are gettincg a request for `/favico.ico` by the browser when the browser first loads a page from your site (which is normal) and your server is not properly handling that request and perhaps confusing it with some other request.  Show us your server code and we can recommend a fix.  Questions here about your code MUST show the relevant code in your question for us to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have included the code that belongs to my /login requests.

Answer (score 3):

You have a race condition in your session between two incoming requests.

Your `app.use()` middleware is going to see the `/favicon.ico` request and will overwrite the `req.session.returnTo` value that your `login` route may have just set.  If these two requests come in one immediately after the other (which is likely when a browser first visits your site), then the `/favicon.ico` route will mess up the session state you just tried to set with the `/login` route.

I can't tell what that middleware is trying to do, but it looks like it's very capable of overwriting stuff in the session that other requests are in the middle of using.  Redirects after login are much, much safer to do by putting the eventual redirect URL in the query parameter.  Then it is stateless on the server and isn't subject to these types of race conditions when there is more than one incoming request to the server form the same user.

---

FYI, you could also fairly easily prevent this particular problem (though not other potential race conditions) by just putting this route handler before your middleware:

```
// put this before your middleware
app.get("/favicon.ico", (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(404);
    // or instead of a 404, send an actual favicon.ico file
    // just don't let routing continue to your middleware
});
```

This would keep your middleware from running at all when `/favicon.ico` is requested and thus prevent that specific place that a race condition with your session data is caused.